# Flutter Web Firebase TypeError: dart.global.firebase.firestore is not a function

Tags: firebase, flutter-web

I'm trying to use Firebase in my flutter web project.
But app can't be run with this message.

```
TypeError: dart.global.firebase.firestore is not a function
at Object.firestore$ [as firestore]
```

My `index.html` looks like this.

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "MY_AUTHDOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "MY_URL",
    projectId: "MY_ID",
    storageBucket: "MY_BUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "MY_ID",
    appId: "MY_APPID",
    measurementId: "MY_ID"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Please share your `pubspec.yaml`.

Answer (score 58):

As [mentioned in the docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview/#3-web-only-add-the-sdk), add this line in `index.html`:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Comment: really? it did for me.

Comment: What does this do and I wonder why is it not mentioned on the official link? Anyone knows? Please explain me

Comment: I also did a flutter upgrade along with this an the web app loaded

Comment: It sort of is and sort of isn't mentioned in the docs. To initialize you add the script firebase-app.js, but then if you want firestore database you add firebase-firestore.js - then you need to do that same thing for any other product you want eg analytics, messaging, storage, etc. just like you would in vanilla js I believe

Comment: Adding to the answer, in my case after updating the above line I had to stop the running project and run it again to make that work.

Comment: @Damandroid It is mentioned in the docs. I've edited the answer to link to it.

Comment: @cubuspl42 the doc doesn't mention it anymore

Comment: @FarhanFarooqui So it seems. I don't know if it's not required anymore, or if it was removed from the docs by mistake.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same thing, to fix it just add this in the index.html at the bottom:

```html
...
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
...
```

just make sure it's after:

```js
....
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
...
```

Comment: If I put this AFTER firebase.initializeApp() then I get Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()

Comment: this is in the dart code, so go and before calling any firebase method, initialize the firebase app, by calling firebase.initializeApp(), just make a splash screen and add this as a future when it finishes, navigate to the next page.

Comment: add the scripts then call the dart.js, in dart code call the firebase app

Answer (score 7):

I think what you are missing is the Firestore SDK to solve that Just go to this URL if you will go with CDN

[Available Firebase JS SDKs (from the CDN)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries)

then add whatever library you are using for your case it's Firestore so it should be this one:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

**add it on the top of your body**

Answer (score 5):

In latest version of FlutterFire, I found these issues and unable to resolve. I resolved this issues while downgrading the dependencies of FlutterFire . Since these are in beta version , we will face these issues. Hope in upcoming version of flutterfire ,these  issues will resolve. Follow these steps:--

**1)** Add these dependencies in **pubsec.yaml** file.

```
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1
```

**2)** Then add these ***scripts***  in **index.html** file.

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

**3)** After that Add these scripts before ***main.dart.js***  **scripts**.

```
 <script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "your api key",
    authDomain: "app_name.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "app_name2",
    storageBucket: "app_name.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "882321312y",
    appId: "1:1782944473493525:web:923488234",
    measurementId: "G-4dmfnsd"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
  </script>
```

**Note:-** *This file is a  generated file while adding WebApp to existing Flutter Project on* ***Firebase Console***.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add **ALL the CDN's** you need from Firebase. **Not only the ones in the example.**

If you didn't do it yet, you have to:

1. Go to your Firebase Console
2. Create a new Web App for your project if you didn't Project settings Web App (The one you created)
3. Select CDN and copy and paste it in your *index.html* inside body, before the `<script>` tag containing the main.dart.js

If you did it, and it is still not working it is because **you need to add the CDN for the other services you are using**.

In my case they were *firebase-auth.js* and *firebase-firestore.js*. But **don't copy it from a reply here because it could be outdated**. You can copy the path for your firebase-app.js which includes the current version.
Mine is `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.2/firebase-app.js">` meaning my current version is 8.4.2 that could not be your case.

Answer (score 2):

insert this script at first before you use any other script because this script needs to get call first then other firebase scripts.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that arrives here, and is just starting with Firebase, you may not have setup your firebase configuration correctly (e.g you're following a tutorial on running Firebase in say, Flutter)

If so, make sure you [follow steps like so](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/friendlyeats-flutter/#4) to add your firebase app configuration info to your HTML file

In short:

- In the Firebase console, select Project Overview in the left navigation bar, and click the Web button under Get started by adding Firebase to your app.
- Give your app a nickname. This is the value that is used across the Firestore console to identify the web version of your app.
- Click Register app.
- After you register your app, the Add Firebase SDK step gives you some code you need to paste into the web/index.html file of your app. Do so!

Answer (score 1):

check the order/presence of  tags ,in the following picture :

[image: index.html]

check this for latest versions : [Firebase JS SDKs(from CDN)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#expandable-8)

Answer (score 0):

check your pubspec.yaml, and import all firebase module. I means, if you have `firebase_auth` in your pubspec.yaml, you should also import script *https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/VERSION/firebase-auth.js*

Answer (score 0):

FYI, here is the list: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls

Every service needs its own CDN import

Answer (score 0):

Just changing values to latest version from 8.6.2 to 8.10.0 solve my error.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```