# Flutter Firebase Web Deploy works, but trying to test run in Android Studio gives blank page

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, web

I seem to be having the opposite issue of what I've been able to find. Deploying the Flutter project with Firebase hosting works, but when I try to test run in Android Studio I get the error "TypeError: dart.global.firebase.Firestore is not a function". I've made sure the index.html file has all the SDKs, and the fact the deployed version works indicates to me that everything is set-up right. My only guess is that there is some issue with Android Studio or my firewall blocking firebase in the localhost, but I can't seem to find a fix. It's not a huge issue cause I can do all the testing with the Android Emulator, but it would be nice to be able to check if the Web version is working properly without having to deploy. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Could this answer your question? [Flutter Web Firebase TypeError: dart.global.firebase.firestore is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248596/flutter-web-firebase-typeerror-dart-global-firebase-firestore-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @FedericoPettinella I found that one already and have the config and all firebase SDKs I used in my index.html file, which is why I'm at a loss